# SMTP : Simple Unix command

Tags: unix, authentication, smtp

What is the command to test a smtp host that whether reachable from my unix machine through port 25 using valid authentication details?

Lets say:

```
host: smtp.gmail.com 
port: 25
username: someusername
password: somepassword
```

how to test this is reachable from my machine?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/

or try this

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:25
```

Comment: try this .. openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:25

Answer (score 0):

`telnet` and here is a [walkthrough](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119)

Comment: I has given for pop and also on MS-DOS...?

Comment: the telnet commands work the same in either DOS or *nix.  The link has been updated for SMTP

Answer (score 0):

You could test whether it is reachable with telnet:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

You don't really need credentials for that - if you can connect, you'll get a response back from the SMTP server (HELO, or EHLO, I think - check [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) (old) or [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) (new, but not clear on status)).